# How do I close a firefox tab from a greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I have a greasemonkey user script with this single line of code...

```
window.close();
```

but firefox does not allow a user script to close a window (as reported by an error message in the error console)

Is there a work around to this problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**You need to change configuration settings of Firefox (about:config) to allow this.**

### Steps:

1. Go to address bar and type **about:config**
2. Go to parameter **dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows**
3. Set its value as **true**

Now your script can close the TAB with 'window.close()'

***eg.***

```
function closeTab(){
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: But wont this allow *all* scripts to close windows? Is there a way way by which only greasemonkey scripts be allowed to close windows?

Comment: Since it is a Firefox config parameter, I dont think there is a way to add trusted script sources or something like that. If you allow a script to close a TAB, an Any script may close a tab.

Answer (score 6):

By now some of the *-monkies* allow the use of *@grant* option to officially unlock commands like *window.close()* without going to *about:config*. For example, in [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php):

```
// @grant window.close
// @grant window.focus
```

(The latter *grant* allows you to re-focus the browser on your window.)
This would remove the error.

***EDIT:*** As [@baptx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1176454/baptx) correctly mentions in the comments, the browser's security options should be set to allow scripts to close windows, too.

Comment: I added a direct link to the documentation. Otherwise, the answer should be fine as people do still find this question nowadays, so there should be is a contemporary answer to it. There would be no errors if the *grant* options I mentioned would be used.

Comment: Working well in Violentmonkey. Thanks

Comment: Did not work with Greasemonkey, I had to set `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` to `true` in `about:config` instead.

Comment: @baptx Yes, indeed. I updated the post to mention the browser's settings; thanks.

Comment: @DDRRSS not that with this setting, it was not necessary to use `@grant window.close` or `@grant window.focus`, with Greasemonkey at least.

Comment: As of Greasemonkey 4.10.0, `@grant window.close` is sufficient to allow window closing functionality, even though the DOM value `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` is still set to `false`

Comment: @MarchHo I cannot confirm that. It doesn't work for me. The tab doesn't close.

Answer (score 4):

Since Firefox treats Greasemonkey code with the same privilages as the script code on external websites, it is not possible to only allow Greasemonkey code to be able to close the windows, but not regular scripts.