# Javascript window.close() for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been searching around for this problem, couldn't find anything that'll solve this. I found a lot of SO questions, but none could help me.

Basically, the problem has no difference from the questions asked, but I tried every answers. No luck.

I want to close the tab of the browser, when a user clicks to a button. I tried the the stuff below:

```
1. <p class="submit"><input type="button" onclick="window.open(window.location, '_self');window.close(); return false;" value="{% trans 'Close' %}"/></p>

2. <p class="submit"><input type="button" onclick="window.open('','_parent',''); window.close(); return false;" value="{% trans 'Close' %}"/></p>

3. <p class="submit"><input type="button" onclick="var win = window.open('', '_self');win.close();return false; " value="{% trans 'Close' %}"/></p>

4. <p class="submit"><input type="button" onclick="window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close(); return false;" value="{% trans 'Close' %}"/></p>
```

None of the above works both in Firefox and Chrome. If one works in Chrome, then it doesn't in Firefox. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Key question is: did you open that tab with JavaScript in the first place?

Comment: I know that question. and the answer is no I didn't. ;) But in the questions asked here, the common sense is that `window.open` can be used to open a window and 'bind' it to `parent` or `self`, and then close it. But what I'm asking is "is there any universal way of doing this in multiple browsers?". From the examples above, obviously `window`'s behavior vary from one browser to another.

Answer (score 0):

Better you write the code inside a function and call that function in each button

try to pass true `window.open('','_parent','', true);` for each creating window

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but no luck either. My function is: `function closeWindow()
    {
        window.open('','_parent','', true);
        console.log("LOGLOGLOG");
        window.close();
        }
`

Comment: is this really required `console.log("LOGLOGLOG");` ? remove and check if worked luckily.

Comment: Firstly I tried without that,but after I put it to test if I actually call this function. It is harmless. Just puts logs to console.

Comment: check this
http://webbysoft.blogspot.in/2013/04/print-part-of-web-page-using-jquery.html


here we are creating a window for printable purpose. working with all browser.. check if this could help you

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to work it out. The thing is that all of the answers are true, along with my trials. All of them work. But in Firefox, one must make `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` true (take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330337/how-do-i-close-a-firefox-tab-from-a-greasemonkey-script/330372#330372)) to make `window.close()` to work. But this can be only done by the user itself. And the another problem is that the window must be opened by the script, if one wants to close by the script. So, I will change my structure in a way that this particular page will be opened by a script.