# Creating a firefox script to close all but one tab?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

im using greasemonkey in firefox and looking to create a script that will close all but a specified tab(or webpage).

Ive little to no clue what im doing, i wanted it to be simple i.e.

```
if (tabs >= 3)
Close all tabs except specified webpage
```

but i just cant seem to figure it out or even find a list of my options =/

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Related: [How do I close a firefox tab from a Greasemonkey script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330337/how-do-i-close-a-firefox-tab-from-a-greasemonkey-script). ... Surprisingly, this question doesn't seem to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, for the same reason that a random webpage can't: it would be a security nightmare. A given page can only control itself and its children.

Comment: security nightmare indeed however im attempting make firefox perform a specific job within a VM and security isnt on my list of concerns. i hear tell of dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows being set to True that will allow for the closure, if this helps in anyway to achive the goal

Comment: @Raine understood, but the answer is still no. You *might* be able to jury-rig something by having each tab communicate with a particular server, which would respond back by telling each tab whether or not to close itself, but you cannot have a script running in one tab close other tabs over which it has no control.

Comment: I see what you mean, I presumed that greasemonkey implemented the scripts globally over firefox and not just within a single page. Thank You for the help!

Comment: Actually, this is probably doable, on Firefox only, and without needing a server (Script instances can communicate directly).  It's a bit messy and I don't see the need though.

Comment: @BrockAdams this is interesting and would be news to me. If you can elaborate on how that could work, I would be very interested!

Comment: @EdCottrell, I don't want to spend any more time on this but in a nutshell: (1) Cripple your Firefox by setting that pref to true, (2) GM script set to run on all sites, (3) GM script instances communicate via postmessage or GM_setValue, (4) when conditions met, close tabs using technique from the linked question (above).